# Synonymize [minmax] and [minimax]

Tags: support, synonym-request

I tried to reject the creation of this excerpt for [minmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minmax) yesterday, with a suggestion to ask here instead, but that didn't work:

> This tag apparently is used as a synonym for "minimax", which seems more appropriate and is better maintained; I would suggest introduction of a tag synonym.

[minimax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimax) has more questions (~200 vs ~60), and more followers (13 vs 2), and appears to be the canonical name for this strategy<sup>1</sup>. The tags are used the same way as far as I can tell.

Can they be synonymized, with [minimax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimax) as the master tag?

<sub><sup>1</sup>Based on the fact that Wikipedia redirects *Minmax* to *Minimax*. Might not be the most authoritative argument ever.</sub>